# data is missing with navigation.goback()

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

In my React Native app, I had three screens like `A` and `B`. I navigate from one screen to another using `react-navigation` version 5.

When I move from `A` to `B` and enter some data in B,  and move from `B` to `A` to verify the data entered in `A` is correct and again entered from `A` to `B`, my data in `B` screen is not there.

I am using `navigation.goBack()`. I am not using any global state. How can I make data entered to be visible even I go back and entered the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `goBack()` to go from B -> A, B gets unmounted and loses params that you initially passed. You would have to either pass it again when going from A -> B or use a central state like `Context`, `Redux` etc.